# cucumber - test view has a specific link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

how do i test that a view has a specific link on it? e.g this is on my view: %div = link_to "something", something_path and i need to test that this link exists on the page....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Webrat matchers with Cucumber:

```
rendered.should have_selector("div") do |div|
  div.should have_selector("a", :href => "url")
end
```